# E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead

Tags: ubuntu, bash

> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

This error occurred while using the command `apt-get update` in bash on ubuntu which is running on windows 10.

I have already tried it many times but the problem persists, even if the command gets executed as the root user.

Error:

[image: error]

Comment: Are the addresses mentioned reachable from your browser / `curl`?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to check (going to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ with your browser) that xenial is not in there (I believe these *old-releases* are used only for out-of-support releases, and since Xenial is a LTS release (Long Term Support) it won't be there soon.

If you have other working sources these *old-releases* ones aren't a problem and may have been put there for later use. If these are the only ones you have then yes, you are in trouble, but we would have to see the whole list.

PS: screenshots are discouraged (clue: we can't see the beginnin of your output). Route the whole output to a file `apt-get update > missing.lst 2>&1` and post the contents here.